# Resolving the error of "SC.Widget function should be given either iframe element or a string specifying id attribute of iframe element"?

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

Context: This is a Soundcloud API javascript and iframe that is suppose to play the correct sound of the soundcloud link when you hover over the link.

Problem: The problem is that I get an error saying "SC.Widget function should be given either iframe element or a string specifying id attribute of iframe element" when I hover over a link. The error occurs at this line of code:

```
widget = SC.Widget(event.currentTarget.childNodes[1]);
```

HTML (Iframe the src is customized to play that particular link):

```
<div class="clickme">
    <iframe  src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com{{-list2[1]-}}&show_artwork=true"
                                        "width=300" height="200" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="display: none" allow="autoplay">
                                </iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript(Soundcloud API):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        let widget;
        let currentWidget;


        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("ready!");
            var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("clickme");
            for (i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
                var list = menu[i];
                var link = String(list.outerHTML);


                if (link.includes('soundcloud')) {
                    list.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (event) {


                        if (event.currentTarget.childNodes[1] == currentWidget) {
                            widget.play();
                        } else {
                            if (widget) {
                                widget.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY);
                                widget.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.READY);
                                widget.unbind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH);
                            }

                            widget = SC.Widget(event.currentTarget.childNodes[1]);
                            /*<!--widget = SC.Widget(idIndex);-->*/

                            widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function () {
                                widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, function () {
                                    // get information about currently playing sound
                                    console.log('sound is beginning to play');

                                });
                                // get current level of volume
                                widget.getVolume(function (volume) {
                                    console.log('current volume value is ' + volume);
                                });
                                // set new volume level
                                widget.setVolume(50);
                                // get the value of the current position
                                widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function () {
                                    // get information about currently playing sound
                                    console.log('replaying sound');
                                    widget.seekTo(0);
                                    widget.play();
                                });
                            });

                            widget.play();
                        }
                        currentWidget = event.currentTarget.childNodes[1];

                    });
                    list.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (event) {

                        console.log('pause soundcloud ');
                        if (widget) {
                            widget.pause();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Comment: Your questions are all following a very specific pattern. You are presenting what appears to be the same or very similar code, over and over, indicating an error message, and saying that you want us to update your code for you. You even make specific demands about what this community can and can not update, and indicate that you want this community to be on stand-by if you have any questions. Please do not confuse the volunteers in this community with *your employees*. To learn more about this community and how we can help, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: ok I apologize but when I do ask questions someone may give me an answer but they never answer clarifying questions that I may have in the comments or no one answers my questions or give me comments at all. But I will work on my attitude.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you have to pass either an `<iframe />` or an ID to an `<iframe />`. It means that `event.currentTarget.childNodes[1]` is probably NOT an `<iframe />` (even less a string representing an DOM's element id).

---

I suggest you `console.log()` the entire event if you want to use mouse events to get corresponding `<iframe />`, or you make a clever use of `id`. Otherwise I'd recommend using a more robust method to get the iframe HTMLElement to pass to the SoundCloud Widget.

---

In the following snippet, [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) is used to find iframes, but jQuery can do the same. Pass your mouse over one of the list elements and you should see the widget's methods logged in the Console.

```js
// Run when DOM is ready

(function() {
  // Make sure the SoundCloud Widget API is loaded in DOM
  if (!(window.SC && window.SC.Widget)) {
    return;
  }

  let currentWidget = null;
  const listItems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

  for (const listItem of listItems) {
    listItem.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
      // Get the <iframe /> HTMLElement
      const iframe = listItem.querySelector('iframe');
      const widget = SC.Widget(iframe);

      // Set the current widget
      currentWidget = widget;

      // The logged object should have the "load", "bind", ... methods
      for (const properties in currentWidget) {
        console.log(properties);
      }

      // Unbind, set volume, ...
      // ...
    });
  }
})()
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/1177612306&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li>
      <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/1177613530&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li>
      <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/1177615096&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li>
      <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/1177644181&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
    </li>
    <li>
      <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/1177647310&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How does this fit into the original code I gave ? Can you integrate your answer with the original code please?